# How can I delete Image Capture's history of past "Scan To" folders?

Tags: macos, image-capture

I have used Apple's *Image Capture* utility to scan to a few different folders on my local storage. As I use each folder, its name accumlates in the pop-up menu of "Scan To:" locations, as a sort of history.

I would like to clear out this history.  How can I do it?  For instance, is the list of recent folders in a plist file somewhere which I can edit or trash?

(What I really want, which is probably the subject of a different question, is to make narrower the Details pane on the right side of the *Image Capture* window. It appears that the utility widens this pane enough to accommodate every name in the Scan To: popup window.)

I am using Mac OS X 10.11.6 *El Capitan*.

Comment: A workaround is nice, but I would still appreciate a better way to clean out this history.

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do in better detail? Screenshots would be nice for others to understand what your question is about. The last paragraph seems to be another question and should be deleted.

Comment: Um, I'm trying to clear out history of past "Scan To" folders in the Image Capture app. Should I word that differently?  Yes, I could illustrate the question more with screenshots etc., but I already got an answer https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/280323/17600 . The last paragraph is indeed "the subject of a different question", but including a higher-level goal is a good practice to avoid the "XY Problem" (see https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/177196). Thank you for the comment.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a workaround that just succeeded for me.

1. In the *Image Capture* utility, open the Scan To: pop-up menu, and remember each folder in the "history list" part. Not just the name of the folder, but its parent folder.
2. Quit the *Image Capture* utility.
3. In Finder, rename each of the folders from the "history list" part. You don't need to delete the folders, but you do need to be sure that nothing exists at the path where each of the folders was.
4. Run the *Image Capture* utility again. Open the Scan To: pop-up menu. The history part should be empty.

Worked for me, on Mac OS X 10.11.6 *El Capitan*.